# What is the meaning of 奇牛? (odd + cow)

Tags: meaning

From the context 奇牛 appears to mean something like customized or "one of a kind", but it's not in my (rather old) dictionary.

---

Edit: context:

奇牛机械，专注小而精机械五金加工，值得信赖，６年老店，高于行业好评率和回头率，您发送图纸给客服，有专门的技术人员为您定制服务

Or is it just a strange proper name?

Comment: do you really have a context for it?

Comment: Yes, where did you see the term 奇牛?

Comment: That was just a brand name I think. 奇牛 connotes very awesome.

Comment: @dan. Thanks. Very awesome. A bit like the niu bi "cool".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Yeah, you got it!

Comment: 奇 here should means 神奇, 奇妙: magical, miraculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no special meaning! It's just a brand of the store or the factory.